MapAreaControllerRoute blocks MapControllerRoute
I have a problem. My MapAreaControllerRoute is blocking MapControllerRoute. That means when I open app in browser localhost:7155 it opens login as normal https://localhost:7155/login.html?ReturnUrl=%2F then after logging in it opens Admin area localhost:7155/Admin/Dashboard/Categories instead of Home controller.
Here is a part of Program.cs:
app.MapAreaControllerRoute(
    name: "areas",
    areaName: "Admin",
    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Dashboard}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

I tried this:
While debugging I saw that route / is a actually the admin area.
Log:

--==[CALLBACK: / ]==---

Here is a part of the code:
await Request.HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal, properties);

string? callbackUrl = Request.Query["ReturnUrl"];

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(callbackUrl))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"---==[ CALLBACK: {callbackUrl} ]==---");
    return Redirect(callbackUrl);
}

Btw my controller automatically redirects to categories action

"Btw my controller automatically redirects to categories action"? The issue must be related to this, could you provide the code about this controller? And how do you configure the post-login redirection?

@YumiaoKong Yes I can. here is the controller. Here in this codeshare link will be easier.


While debugging I saw that route / is an actually the admin area.

In general, routes with areas should be placed earlier as they're more specific than routes without an area. And matches from a route that appears earlier have a higher priority. So, when executing the redirection, it will match the MapAreaControllerRoute first.
That's why the program goto the "localhost:7155/Admin/Dashboard/Categories", because the "localhost:7155/" matches the first route map, then use the default controller and action as "localhost:7155/Admin/Dashboard/Index".
So, the solution is adding a route attribute "[Route("/")]" to the Home/Index action, the program will first match the attribute.
[Route("/")]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

